# Closure of the algebra and Closure of the set

Tags: real-analysis

The closure of the set $E$ is defined as $\overline{E} = E \cup E'$, where $E$ is the set of the limit point of $E$.

The closure $\mathscr{B}$ of the algebra $\mathscr{A}$ is defined as the set of the all functions which is the limits of uniformly convergent sequences of members of $\mathscr{A}$.

It seems that $\mathscr{B}$ is only similar to $E'$. How to unify them as consistent?

Comment: The metric you're using in $\mathscr A$ is the uniform metric, that is $$d(f,g)=\sup_{x\in K}|f(x)-g(x)|$$ where $K$ is the underlying (compact) set. This endows $\mathscr A$ with a metric space structure.

Answer (score 1):

Admittedly, $\mathscr B$ looks a lot like $E'$. But we can get an "$E$ equivalent" for $\mathscr B$ in this sense: let $a\in\mathscr A$, then the sequence $(a,a,a,\cdots)$ is uniformly convergent, so every $a\in\mathscr A$ can be identified with an element in $\mathscr B$.

My question would be the opposite: why is the $E$ necessary for topological spaces? It really seems like $E'$ should be enough. In fact, it's close to enough; you just need $E$ for the isolated points.

Comment: Yes, $E' = \phi$ when $E$ only contains the isolated points.

Comment: @xbjin: Actually, you can say more than that: $E-E'$ is precisely the set of isolated points in $E$.

Answer (score 1):

Remarks:

1. (Eric Stucky has already given a concise general answer that overlaps with this part.) In general, if $E$ is a subset of a metric space, then $\overline E$ is equal to the set of all limits of sequences in $E$.  This does not mean that all elements of $\overline E$ are limit points of $E$, because limits of sequences from $E$ need not be limit points of $E$.  Example: If $E=\{1,1/2,1/3,\ldots\}$ in $\mathbb R$ with the usual metric, then $\overline E=\{0,1,1/2,1/3,\ldots\}$, and $0$ is the only limit point of $E$.  However, for each positive integer $n$, $\frac1n$ is the limit of the sequence $(\frac1n,\frac1n,\frac1n,\ldots)$ in $E$.
2. If your metric space is the algebra $\ell^\infty(X)$ of bounded real or complex-valued functions on some set $X$ with distance $d(f,g)=\sup_{x\in X}|f(x)-g(x)|$, and $\mathscr A$ is a subalgebra of $\ell^\infty(X)$, then, unless $\mathscr A$ consists of only the $0$ function, every element of $\mathscr A$ is in fact a limit point of $\mathscr A$, so in this case it turns out to be true that $\overline{\mathscr A}=\mathscr A'$.  The reason is that if $0\neq f\in \mathscr A$, then $f$ is the uniform limit of the sequence $((1+1/n)f)_{n=1}^\infty$, and $0$ is the uniform limit of the sequence $(\frac1n f)_{n=1}^\infty$.

In summary, the two notions are generally consistent without implying that $\overline E=E'$, but in your particular case (if $\mathscr A\neq\{0\}$), or generally for nonzero subspaces of normed vector spaces, $\overline E=E'$ holds, which is equivalent to saying that nonzero subspaces do not have isolated points.

Comment: Why exclude the 0 function?  Isn't $0$ the uniform limit of the sequence $(\frac{1}{n}f)_{n = 1}^{\infty}$?

Comment: @xbjin: Yes, I mentioned that you get $0$ as a limit point if there exists nonzero $f$ in your algebra.  If you mean why exclude the case where $\mathscr A=\{0\}$, I meant that in that case $\mathscr A'=\varnothing$ while $\overline{\mathscr A}=\mathscr A=\{0\}$ (the only sequence in $\mathscr A$ would be $(0,0,0,\ldots)$), but in all other cases $\overline{\mathscr A}=\mathscr A'$.

Answer (score 0):

You are just taking closures of sets in different [metric spaces](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Metric_space) (using different metrics to define "closure" and "limit point"). You just need to identify in which sets $E$ and $\cal{A}$ lie in, and what metric your associating with each of those two sets.